# Sharepoint 2007 having a problem with all InfoPath forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am using a Sharepoint 2007 and recently having a problem with all InfoPath forms through Sharepoint. I tried restarting the Sharepoint server and it didn't work. I have tried re-publishing the forms but it didn't work neither. The error says that "The server is currently being taken down for maintenance. Check with your system administrator to see when this server is scheduled to come back online." Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Central Administrator->Operations->Global Configuration-> Quiesce Farm` and check if the status is Quiesced. If it is reset the farm.